# Azure DevOps Pipelines - .artifactignore not working properly with pipeline artifact

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I need once more your swarm intelligence with this issue.

**Background:**
I publish powershell modules to azure artifacts using azure pipelines (like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows).
I have different files (Folder: build_scripts) in my repository that i do not want to publish to azure artifacts. So i came to .artifactignore

**Current situation:**
No mather what i try the files in the folder "build_scripts" stays part of the artifact.

Let me show:
My Repository:

[image]

Pipeline yaml:

```
  - main

name: 'PowerShell Module Project'

variables:
  major: 1
  minor: 0
  patch: $(Build.BuildID)
  buildVer: $(major).$(minor).$(Build.BuildID)

pool: DevPool

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build_scripts/build.ps1'
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'pack'
        packagesToPack: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PowerShellModuleProject.nuspec'
        versioningScheme: byEnvVar
        versionEnvVar: buildVer
        buildProperties: 'VERSIONHERE=$(buildVer)'
    - task: CopyFiles@2   
      displayName: 'Copy .artifactignore'   
      inputs:     
        SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'     
        Contents: '**/.artifactignore'     
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'     
        flattenFolders: true
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        artifactName: 'NuGetPackage'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          artifactName: 'NuGetPackage'
          itemPattern: '**'
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        inputs:
          command: 'push'
          packagesToPush: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*$(buildVer).nupkg'
          nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
          publishVstsFeed: 'MYProjectName/MyPipelineName'
```

My .artifactignore file:

```
build_scripts/**
```

The artifactignore file is in the correct directory using the copy job, like suggested here on stack overflow ([PublishPipelineArtifact .artifact ignore not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042995/publishpipelineartifact-artifact-ignore-not-recognized)).
This can also be verified when i take a look at the pipeline run log:

```
Using .artifactignore file located at: C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.232.0\_work\3\a\.artifactignore for globbing
2 files processed.
```

But at the end, when i install the powershell module from the repository, the files in the build_scripts are still present

[image]

Now i ran out of ideas.
Does anyone have a hint what i am doing wrong here ?

Thanks in advance

**Requested additional information from Kevin Lu-MSFT:**

Screenshot of the artifact content:
[image]

Pipeline log -> Publish Pipeline artifacts:

```
Starting: PublishPipelineArtifact
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish Pipeline Artifacts
Description  : Publish (upload) a file or directory as a named artifact for the current run
Version      : 1.199.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact
==============================================================================
Artifact name input: NuGetPackage
Uploading pipeline artifact from C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.232.0\_work\3\a for build #36
Using default max parallelism.
Max dedup parallelism: 192
DomainId: 0
ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session a79f1780-5577-434e-9f9e-3f5e8b41c6ab
Hashtype: Dedup1024K
DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session a79f1780-5577-434e-9f9e-3f5e8b41c6ab
Using .artifactignore file located at: C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.232.0\_work\3\a\.artifactignore for globbing
2 files processed.
Processed 2 files from C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.232.0\_work\3\a successfully.
Uploaded 48,185 out of 48,185 bytes
Content upload is done!

Content upload statistics:
Total Content: 96.0 KB
Physical Content Uploaded: 41.4 KB
Logical Content Uploaded: 48.2 KB
Compression Saved: 6.8 KB
Deduplication Saved: 47.9 KB
Number of Chunks Uploaded: 3
Total Number of Chunks: 5

Associated artifact 22 with build 36
ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session a79f1780-5577-434e-9f9e-3f5e8b41c6ab
Uploading pipeline artifact finished.
Finishing: PublishPipelineArtifact
```

Comment: Can you share the screenshot about the Pipeline Artifacts content? When you use the  .artifactignore file, can you see the following log in the **Pipeline log -> Publish Pipeline artifacts** step: **Processing .artifactignore file surfaced 1 files. Total files under source directory: 3**

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT: I added the requested information. Thank you

Comment: @LKo.exp An alternative is to use exclusion like this- - task: CopyFiles@2   
  displayName: 'Copy necessary files'   
  inputs:     
    SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'     
    Contents: |
      **/*
      !build_scripts/
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'     
    flattenFolders: true

Comment: @SiddheshDesai: Thank you for your suggestion. I would see this as my backup solution :). In general i would prefer the .artifactignore file, because its easier to maintain for my collegues. But although thank you !

Comment: @LKo.exp The cause of the issue is that the nuget pack step will pack the build_script folder.  So when you download the nuget package, it will show the unexpected folder. The .artifactignore file will not work for the nuget pack step. You can refer to the methods in the answer and check if it can work for you.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT: Thank you for your answer. Okay unfortunate, but then i will try the method suggested by SiddheshDesai

Comment: @LKo.exp The method shared by SiddheshDesai will not avoid the nuget pack to package the build_script. It will only remove the files in build artifacts. But currently, the pipeline artifacts already don't contain the files. I am afraid that it may not suitable for you.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT: Yeah i see it right now. The build_scripts folder is still included. Perhaps i need to arrange my self with this folder in the nuget package. Or do you know any other alternative ?

Comment: I suggest that you can refer to the methods in the answer and modify the pipeline to exclude the build_script folder.

Comment: On the other hand, you can also adjust the files in your repo to let the nuget pack to pack the files without build_script

Comment: Okay, will try that :) do you have any information on how to adjust the files ?

Comment: EDIT: I got it through editing the nuspec file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452608/how-to-exclude-a-folder-from-a-nuget-package

Comment: @LKo.exp This should be decided based on the actual situation.  You may consider separating the build_script into a separate repo, and then use repo resource to reference it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines  Or you can put files other than build_script into a separate folder, and finally execute nuget pack in the new folder.  These are my initial thoughts. You can refer to it and conduct further testing. If these methods are useful to you, you may consider accepting my answer. Thanks

Comment: @LKo.exp Yes. The SO ticket you shared also can work. The method is same as the -exclude argument in the answer.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT. Thank you very much. You definitly put me on the right trail ! I accepted your answer. Interestingly stackoverflow didnt diplay me your answer until a few minutes ago. So i was a little confused at first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, the build_scripts folder doesn't exist in the Pipeline Artifacts content.

This means that the build_scripts folder has been added to the nuget package when running the Nuget Pack task.

In this case, when you download the nuget package, it will still contains the build_scripts folder.

Refer to this doc: [Use .artifactignore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/artifactignore?view=azure-devops)

> The .artifactignore is a text file that controls which files are uploaded when you publish a Universal Package or a Pipeline Artifact.

So the .artifactignore will not work when running the nuget pack task.

To solve this issue, you can refer to the following methods:

Method1: you can add the **-Exclude** argument in the Nuget pack task to exclude the build_scripts folder.

For example:

```
name: 'PowerShell Module Project'

variables:
  major: 1
  minor: 0
  patch: $(Build.BuildID)
  buildVer: $(major).$(minor).$(Build.BuildID)

pool: DevPool

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build_scripts/build.ps1'
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'NuGet custom'
      inputs:
        command: custom
        arguments: 'pack $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PowerShellModuleProject.nuspec  -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -Properties VERSIONHERE=$(buildVer) -version $(buildVer) -Exclude "build_scripts/*"'
    - task: CopyFiles@2   
      displayName: 'Copy .artifactignore'   
      inputs:     
        SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'     
        Contents: '**/.artifactignore'     
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'     
        flattenFolders: true
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        artifactName: 'NuGetPackage'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          artifactName: 'NuGetPackage'
          itemPattern: '**'
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        inputs:
          command: 'push'
          packagesToPush: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*$(buildVer).nupkg'
          nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
          publishVstsFeed: 'MYProjectName/MyPipelineName'
```

Method2: you can use the nuget pack command in the deploy stage. And in the build stage, you can publish all files to pipelines artifacts(use .artifactignore to exclude build_script file).

For example:

```
name: 'PowerShell Module Project'

variables:
  major: 1
  minor: 0
  patch: $(Build.BuildID)
  buildVer: $(major).$(minor).$(Build.BuildID)

pool: DevPool

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build_scripts/build.ps1'
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.sourcesdirectory)'
        artifactName: 'NuGetPackage'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          artifactName: 'NuGetPackage'
          itemPattern: '**'
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        inputs:
          command: 'pack'
          packagesToPack: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/PowerShellModuleProject.nuspec'
          versioningScheme: byEnvVar
          versionEnvVar: buildVer
          buildProperties: 'VERSIONHERE=$(buildVer)'
          packDestination: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        inputs:
          command: 'push'
          packagesToPush: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/*$(buildVer).nupkg'
          nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
          publishVstsFeed: 'MYProjectName/MyPipelineName'
```